# React Live search feature working but not cancelling previous request in network tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, livesearch

I am following a tutorial on "alligator.io".
The link is  : https://alligator.io/react/live-search-with-axios/

Code::
App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { avoidUnnecessarySearch } from './utils';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    movies: null,
    loading: false,
    value: ''
  };

  search = async val => {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    const res = await avoidUnnecessarySearch(
      `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=${val}&api_key=aac2c5b048fc2fae15675475f98c6ef7`
    );
    const movies = await res ? res.results:'';
    console.log(movies);

    // this.setState({ movies, loading: false });
  };

  onChangeHandler = async e => {
    this.search(e.target.value);
    this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
  };


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <input
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={e => this.onChangeHandler(e)}
            placeholder="Type something to search"
            />

      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default App;
```

## Utils.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

const makeRequestCreator = () => {
  let token;
  return async (query) => {
   // Check if we made a request
   if(token){
     // Cancel the previous request before making a new request
     token.cancel()
   }
   // Create a new CancelToken
   token = axios.CancelToken.source()
   try{
     const res = await axios(query, {cancelToken: token.token})
     const result = res.data
     return result;
   } catch(error) {
       if(axios.isCancel(error)) {
         // Handle if request was cancelled
         console.log('Request canceled', error.message);
       } else {
         // Handle usual errors
         console.log('Something went wrong: ', error.message)
       }
   }
 }
}

export const avoidUnnecessarySearch = makeRequestCreator();
```

Problem::
The trouble is that even though everything is working but the code that is written in utils.js file for cancelling all previous requests before making a new request is not working properly and i get a network request for each keypress or alphabet that i type in search-box.

My intention is that if I am typing "spiderman" then I should get search only for spiderman not for "s" or "p" or "i" or "d" or "e" or "r" or "m" or "a" and request for these should be cancelled outright to avoid network burden.
Any insight will be helpful here .

Answer (score 0):

I copied the exact same code and run in code sandbox. It's working.
Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-mountain-zgqqt 
As you can see when I typed `spiderman` all the other requests got cancelled and only successful hit for the word `spiderman`.
[API Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKQ6J.png). Lmk if you face any issues.